# Improper integral of $\int_0^\infty \cos (t^2x) dt$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

When I try to do the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|k|}}$, an improper integral shows up: $$\int_0^\infty \cos (t^2x) dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8 |x|}}.$$
Can anyone show why?  (Contour integral is welcomed.)

Comment: Google Fresnel integral.

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Evaluation

Comment: The FT pair looks symmetrical, what an elegant result.

Comment: It converges due to the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma), and it is related to the value of the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) by way of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).